# automatically authenticate user using c# membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using c# membership provider and I get the username from a query string. Now I need to   check if the username exist if it does I need to automatically authenticate the user.

How do I check if the user exists in the membership database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an SSO solution, you can find more information here

http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2004/06/09/ssoformsauth.aspx

Comment: i am looking for an SSO solution but the 2 application are using different databases and the 2 projects are under the same solution

Comment: Then you need to pass encrypted username with an expiring timestamp to the second server and authenticate the user there using the technique explained in the above link.

Comment: if (user != "")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false);} i did this it worked but i need to refresh the page for the cookie to take effect and authenticate the user

Answer (score 2):

If you have a password:

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, "password")) 
 {
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
     Response.Redirect("~/welcome.aspx");
 }
```

or if you just want to check if the user exist and log them in

```
 if (Membership.GetUser(userName) != null) 
 { 
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true); 
     Response.Redirect("~/welcome.aspx");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) method. If the user exists, you can then use [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd.aspx) to authenticate the user.

Comment: ok i got the user information and i found him in my database and everything is ok but how to authenticate him ? i mean how i can make him login to the site and display the msg for example : welcome ...

Comment: I amended the answer to explain.